# Why does Schopenhauer think aesthetic experience is the suspension of pain and desire?

Tags: aesthetics, schopenhauer, art

In an [discussion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBkyXgcxYOo) about Schopenhauer , the French philosophy teacher Christophe Salaün says:

"L'expérience esthétique est la suspension momentanée de la douleur, du désir. En supprimant provisoirement la douleur elle nous fait rentrer dans une sorte d'autre monde où le temps n'existe plus."

Translation:

"Aesthetic experience is the suspension of pain, of desire. In suspending pain tentatively, we enter in another world, a world where time doesn't exist anymore."

How does the aesthetic experience suspend pain and desire? Is he referring to the experience we have with music when we 'forget' ourselves and the world around us?

Comment: Could you please add a bit context to the author and the project for those of us who do not understand French? A quick google search informed me that he worked quite a lot on Schopenhauer (limited knowledge of French), but I am not sure whether he paraphrases/explains Schopenhauer in the quote or having a point of his own.

Comment: You should have mentioned in your post that Salaün refers to  Schopenhauer's philosophy, where aesthetic experience, a contemplative, disinterested attitude, is identified with suspension of the Will, which is the source of all pain and suffering in the world. Schopenhauer was influenced by the Buddhist conception that desires ("will") are the cause of all suffering and to end one we have to end the other. See [Soll's Willing and Nothingness, p.94](https://books.google.com/books?id=QpKimnHm5iUC&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

Comment: Schopenhauer was a avid reader of the Upanishads. I think rather than the word aesthetic, which carries certain connotations, a better word would be mystical. the mystical state of samadhi, or satori, is described in the manner quoted.

Comment: @Conifold I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. Aesthetic experiences make us forget about the pain of our existence.

For Schopenhauer, we are manifestations of will. The will always craves and desires. He pretty much agrees with Buddhism that all life is suffering because we have urges that we are mostly unable to satisfy. We have personal goals we will not reach, we fall in unrequited love with people that will not reciprocate our feelings, etc.

His magnum opus is called "The World and Will and Idea". We have access to the world from 2 sides, from the side of will, and from the side of idea. The world as idea does not exist independently of the will, like it does for Hegel, it it founded on the will. It is weaker than the will since it is derived from the will.

We are powerless against the will, but we can temporarily trick it with aesthetic experiences (and not only with them, there are 4 such cures). Those experiences let us fully enter the world as idea, we separate / are not conscious of the world as will in those moments.

Interestingly, Einstein fully agreed with Schopenhauer on this point. He said that his goal in studying and doing physics was not to make revolutions in science, or to get fame, it was simply to forget about his problems for a little while. Another giant of physics that read Schopenhauer his whole life was Erwin Schrodinger.